# Fit an image into a material-ui grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, material-ui

How to resize the image within grid, because every image has different dimensions so as they behave in Grid. I want to fit an image on top horizontal Grid, but when i set my desired height (e.g. height:'300px') instead of stretching and fitting into container, image become cropped. What should i do so that any image can fit into Grid container.

```js
const backgroundImage = require('../../styles/img/grid/badshah.jpg');

export default function Saifulmalok() {
const classes = useStyles();
return (
<React.Fragment>
<Container maxWidth="lg"   >

<Grid xs={12} justify="space-between"  
style={{backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,   
 height:'300px',
  marginTop: 20, 
  backgroundSize:'cover'
  }}>
</Grid>

</Container>
</React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use `backgroundSize: 'contain'` and `backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'`.
If you wanna have a list of images, try to have images with same dimension to have a monolithic design.

Comment: Image is on left side of the screen, its not covering whole grid.